# unhandledrejection not working in Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, promise

I'm trying to get a simple [unhandledrejection](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/unhandledrejection) handler working in Google Chrome.

If I paste the following code into a JSFiddle and run it in Chrome, I get an error box, as expected:

```
window.addEventListener('unhandledrejection', function(e) {
    console.log(e);
    alert(e.reason);
});
new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    setTimeout(function() {
        return reject('oh noes');
    }, 2000);
});
```

If I create an HTML file with an embedded script and load it in Chrome as a `file:///` URL, I get a message box, as expected.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<body>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    window.addEventListener('unhandledrejection', function(e) {
        console.log(e);
        alert(e.reason);
    });
    new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        setTimeout(function() {
            return reject('oh noes');
        }, 2000);
    });
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

If I create separate HTML and JS files and load it in Chrome as a `file:///` URL, I get Chrome's standard 'Uncaught (in promise)' console error but no message box.

index.html:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<body>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

app.js:

```
window.addEventListener('unhandledrejection', function(e) {
    console.log(e);
    alert(e.reason);
});
new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    setTimeout(function() {
        return reject('oh noes');
    }, 2000);
});
```

What's going on?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

As best as I can tell, the cause is that "unhandledrejection" event handlers are silently ignored if they originate from a different script origin.  (For more info, see MDN on [same-origin policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy).) Chrome is [very strict](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=512542) with file URLs' security origins in particular, but I've found that unknowingly breaking the same origin policy can happen for other reasons too (such as developing in webpack-dev-server with Chrome Dev Tools open).  See [this Chrome issue](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=655694) for discussion.

A workaround is to test in a simpler, closer-to-production environment: running over a plain HTTP server ([SimpleHTTPServer](http://www.linuxjournal.com/content/tech-tip-really-simple-http-server-python) works well), with Dev Tools closed if necessary.

Comment: The relevant issue for webpack-dev-server https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/6099

Comment: Long story short, add a crossorigin="anonymous" your script tag and Chrome starts to fire the unhandledrejection events.

Comment: now, in chrome 100 console also not work

Answer (score 3):

This can be solved by adding `crossorigin="anonymous"` to the script that is causing unhandled rejection.

`<script src="non-default-domain.js" type="text/javascript" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>`